# CRM 2011 Search Exact Match

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have a problem with CRM 2011 , I currently have 22 users . In the Accounts or Cases entities some of them can search with half of the word and some of them have to enter the whole exact name to get answers which is really annoying . Can someone help please?

Thank You !

Comment: Maybe they are using different views ?

Answer (score 0):

By default you can add which fields will be searched to the Quick Search view, see how [Example](http://businesswithcrm.wordpress.com/tag/configure-quick-find-in-crm-2011/).

You still can use wild cards "*" (ex: "*John*") when performing a Quick Find Search.

Comment: Hi this is not the problem I am facing  , when i search for "Shanks" Let's Say , I have to input "Shanks" while other users on the same CRM Server can input "Sha" and they will get Shanks .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure they use all the same view (the Quick find one usually) and, from

`Settings->Customizations->Customize the system->Entities->(Select the desired entity)->Views` and then open the view users are using then you can set the filter criteria to whatever you would like for each fields.

I don't think you can enforce a view on users though, but my guess if for some users partial searches work, and for some others not, they are probably using different views.

EDIT: You can select said view and in `More Actions` above set it to default view. Then again, users are still able to create personal views and set them as default...

Answer (score 0):

Surely you mean that your users search their wanted fields in quick find area that this is system view and the problem posed do not have relation to view's setting, because it was the same for all the user's.
so i guess this problem arises out: keyboard not uniform.......